`TypeId` of `fn` is different even when arguments and results have the same types
The TypeId of two fn types with same argument and result types differ b/w taking the TypeId in a non-generic function vs a generic function instantiated with the same type:
In this rust program (permalink), while the same TypeId is printed for &dyn I (line 4) and &T (line 12), when the types are wrapped into a fn type, the printed TypeId is different (line 5 and line 13).
use std::any::TypeId;

fn main() {
    dbg!(TypeId::of::<&dyn I>());
    dbg!(TypeId::of::<fn(&dyn I)>());
    f::<dyn I>();
}

trait I {}

pub fn f<T: ?Sized + 'static>() {
   dbg!(TypeId::of::<&T>());
   dbg!(TypeId::of::<fn(&T)>());
}

My goal is to be able to store fn pointers in an Any object so that I can downcast them later. But that isn't working (presumably because the TypeIds don't match).

The problem is that the implicitly derived lifetime of the dyn I differs, for fn(&dyn I) it's the unnamed lifetime '_ that is also assigned to the reference, for f::<dyn I> because you restrict the type parameter to T: 'static it's inferred to be 'static so both parameters to TypeId::of are in fact different types fn(&'_ (dyn I + '_)) vs fn(&'_ (dyn I + 'static))
I don't think it's possible for the function to relax that requirement to (dyn I + '_) so you'll have to be more strict on the bare version:
use std::any::TypeId;
#[test]
fn same_type() {
    let bare = TypeId::of::<fn(&(dyn I + 'static))>();
    let call = f::<dyn I>();
    assert_eq!(bare, call);
}

pub fn f<T: ?Sized + 'static>() -> TypeId {
    TypeId::of::<fn(&T)>()
}

trait I {}

